# Desire to print out my entire website's HTML/CSS

Tags: printing, html, website, css, httrack

I recently migrated a website from one hosting company to another and changed the domain name at the same time (they did it all). It's up and running but with lots of bad links - I'm on my own now and want to print out all the HTML/CSS and search for the old links so I can change them. I looked at HTTRACK, can't get it to do it. Appreciate any and all thoughts for other options. Thanks!

Comment: There is no magic to this: You need to download all of the HTML and CSS on your own from the new hosting company, use a text editor to search and replace items and then upload it back to your new hosting company.

Comment: You can use `sed` or `awk` for that.

Comment: It's your website. Do you have a local copy of the code or did you use some sort of online site builder to construct it?

Answer (score 0):

HTTRACK cannot do it, since it follows links when downloading,
and your links point to nowhere.

The hosting company is supposed to give you some method for
directly accessing your files on their server.
You will be using either a browser, SSH or Remote Desktop,
depending on the company.

You can then download all the bad files, fix the links and upload again.

I remark that your links should have been written relative to the root URL.
Using absolute URL just causes the very problem that you are experiencing.

Reference (many more are available):
[What is the difference between a relative and absolute URLs?](https://www.pipeten.com/support/scripting/what-is-the-difference-between-a-relative-and-absolute-urls)